# xamarin.ios: Mono.Data.Sqlite cannot load at release build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this error which generate at release build?

"Error  Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Data.Sqlite, "
This error only shows when I select "Release" -> F6

However, When I build/compile in debug mode it does not generate any error and run without any problem. I am running my app through mac agent.

I don't know if above info is enough or not. Please let me know if I can provide you more details. I would really appreciate your help..

Thanks!

Comment: What Linker configuration are you using for Release builds?

Comment: Try adding System.Data.SQLite.